# Select top year and term for each student

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I want to return each student final semester record from these tables.

Table: dbo.Stdetail

```
StID    YearID  TermID
2           1    1
3           1    1
3           2    1
3           2    2
3           3    1
3           3    2
4           1    1
4           1    2
5           1    1
5           1    2
```

Table: dbo.lastyear

```
StID    YearID  TermID
1          5     1
2          5     1
2          6     2
3          5     1
3          6     2
```

From these two tables I want to return final yearID and term ID. 
Desired output:

```
StID    yearID   TermID
 1          5     1
 2          6     2
 3          6     2
 4          1     2
 5          1     2
```

Comment: Show desired output and explain why. Does "final" mean just the highest-numbered IDs of each kind? What if years or terms were inserted out of order? Or does it mean the IDs from the row with the highest `StID`? and so on, and so forth.

Comment: dbo.Stdetail is the active students list and final is the graduated. So i want to pull all students record like above desired output

Comment: Each students top year iD and term id for example studentid 3 has 6 and  2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to union together dbo.Stdetail and dbo.lastyear and then apply use `row_number()` to identify the most last record for each student.  Like this:

```
;with cte as (select *
                   , row_number() over (partition by StID order by YearID desc, TermID desc) rn
                from (select StID, YearID, TermID from dbo.Stdetail
                      union 
                      select StID, YearID, TermID from dbo.lastyear) x
             )
select *
  from cte
 where rn = 1
```

Comment: All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

Comment: The union-ed tables in the example above do both have the same columns.

Comment: No... they have some different columns as well

Comment: I updated the query to list the union columns explicitly.